# catalyst 6509 using fxs card to convert analog to sip for an external pbx?

Tags: cisco-catalyst, voip

I am looking in to getting a 6509 with supervisor 2 module.  I noticed that there was a fxs card avaiable and started to wonder if you had to use the unified software on a pc or if it would be possible to have the fxs card have a astrisk or other non cisco pbx handle the call processing.  I have an astrisk server handling all the digital voip traffic and was going to get a pci card to handle the few analog lines i need to incorporate eventually.  I would much prefer to be able to stick the analog card in the switch and leave the pbx vm free to switch hosts as needed for fallover and such.

I have been reading through the cisco site and get conflicting answers including that it does and does not support being used on ios.  Having some one who has dealt with these before would be of great assistance.

Comment: Thank you for asking; could you be a little more explicit about how we can help?  The question is unclear right now

Comment: can the FXO module be configured so that it has the astrisk pbx server manage all the call functions/features.  I just want it to turn analog in to sip so astrisk can manage extension dialing voice mail and all the other functions of the voip system. I am not to keen on cisco unified communication manager and the apparent need for an extra system to run the manager software on.

Comment: Could you provide the link where you saw an FXO module compatible with a 6500 chassis?  I don't believe Cisco is supporting/selling anything like that at this time.  At least not on 6500's running IOS.  There used to be some voice line cards available in Cat OS days... But that was some time ago.

Comment: you are correct it is an old card. WS-SVC-CMM-24FXS,  It has several conflicting answers on the cisco site. I found today another pdf at work that lists cat min version... and ios native min version for the 24fxo yet several other docs list it as cat only and the same for supervisor 2 engine.  I found a pdf on the cisco site that appears to allow engine 1a and 2 to be upgraded to ios as well.   Unfortunatly I did not bring them home with me so I would have to dig them up again tomorrow.

Comment: Spare part number| WS-SVC-CMM-24FXS=
Cisco IOS Software (minimum) on Cisco CMM
 
12.4(8a) or later

Cisco Catalyst OS (minimum)
8.4.1 or later

Native Cisco IOS Software (minimum)
12.2(18)SXF3 or later     from http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/product_data_sheet0900aecd8066426f.html

Comment: You are alternating between sometimes saying FXO, and sometimes saying FXS.  Which do you need?  Ports for connecting stations (FXS), or ports for connecting to the PSTN (FXO)?

Comment: sorry i realised i put the wrong term in and couldent edit the comments.  i need analog phones to connect to the pbx I have. fxs

Comment: I asked the question on the cisco forums and yes it is possible to use the 24FXS card and send the traffic to a sip proxy that works with asterisk. Thus skipping the need for the unified manager software by cisco. 

I still need to figure out if that card is able to run with Native IOS 12.2 as the above pdf lists a native and catOS minimum version suggesting at some point it was made compatible with native.  I have seen a comparison of hardware supported between catOS and IOS that listed the 24fxs card as catOS only I am not sure which is newer or correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WS-SVC-CMM-24FXS can be set in the CMM to use a non cisco sip proxy which will allow any PBX capible of working with a sip proxy to manage the calls.

I also looked through the release notes of the 12.2 IOS release and it DOES list the FXS card as compatible.